# What's the difference between Firebase hosting "site" and "target" when sharing resources between multiple sites?

Tags: firebase-hosting

I need to deploy multiple sites sharing the same Firestore resources.

In file `firebase.json` I can use the `hosting` section:

```
"hosting": {
    "site": "mysite1",  // change this to mysite2 for another site
    "public": "dist",
...
```

What are the differences in using a different `target` instead of `site`?

```
"hosting": {
    "target": "mytarget1",  // change this to mytarget2 for another site
    "public": "dist",
...
```

**EDIT**

Some links for `target` mode:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/targets
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/multisites#define_hosting_config

Comment: I don't see either of those properties listed anywhere in the documentation for hosting config. https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config

Comment: I edited the question adding links for target mode.
Honestly, in this moment I don't recall where I found the `site` version, but I actually tried it, and I deployed 3 sites in this way, so it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the second link, you can read

Important: Using deploy targets is the recommended way to configure deploys for multiple Hosting sites.
If you previously configured your `firebase.json` file by explicitly referencing your site-name, you should edit your `firebase.json` configuration and your CLI commands to use deploy **targets** instead.

So, implicitly it speaks about a site-name configuration, it is the site: version, probably obsolete now.